# F-Script: Get object reference from object-browser to script-console

Tags: f-script

I am trying to figure out how to get an object I have found via the object-browser of F-Script to the script console. For example, I found an instance of NSString at adress 0x234243242 as the object explorer tells me. Now, I would like to call an instance method on it via the script-console (I know that I can call a method on it via the object-browser).

Can anyone give a hint how i could do this? Neither the F-Script documentation, nor Google was able to provide me an answer for this, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click the "Name" button in the browser, give it a name, then use that name in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this directly with F-Script either, but here's a way that integrates Cocoa with F-Script pointers:

```
ptr := FSPointer objectPointer
scanner := NSScanner scannerWithString:'0x234243242'
scanner scanHexLongLong:ptr
object := ptr at:0
```

Comment: I was guessing that it might be somehow possible via copying the memory address and playing around with it; but, I was expecting that this is a common task and might be easier to achiche. I mean, when you attache yourself to a running app for reverse engineering or so, this would be a really cool feature. Not only using the UI, but actually interacting with the objects easily in a small script...